# Trying to install a Python package from Github

Tags: python, git

Trying to run the following:

```
(venv)MacBook-Pro:my_project_folder gbha$ sudo install git://github.com/venthur/python-ardrone.git
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

I keep getting this message and am pretty sure it's stopping python-ardrone library from installing since I can't import the appropriate class from the file afterwards.

Comment: Clone the repo: `git clone git://github.com/venthur/python-ardrone.git` and then follow the instructions on the github page: https://github.com/venthur/python-ardrone

Comment: I've never seen `install` used in that fashion. Would recommend either `git clone ...` or `pip install git+https://yoururl...`.

Comment: pip install won't work because there's no `setup.py` in that project. OP will have to read the instructions after import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `install` command which is not a command used for installing python packages.

you should use `pip install git+https://github.com/venthur/python-ardrone`

Comment: so you can't install it by pip! you should clone it by git and use the packages manually or write a little setup.py for it